# Git checkout branch results in fatal: Unknown commit

Tags: git

```
gco -b test
```

> Switched to a new branch 'test'
>
> fatal: Unknown commit origin/test

Whenever I create a new local branch off develop I get an error,

> fatal: Unknown commit.

The remote origin exists and everything seems to work fine.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What git version do you use? and do you have any commits in your repo?

Comment: Do you have a `post-checkout` hook? This seems like an error that would come from that hook.

Comment: Have you tried using `git checkout -b test` instead? When asking questions, it is better to specify the full command. That way, people do not have to guess what alias you have defined. But I guess the "normal" gco alias would be `alias gco='git checkout'`, and I assume this is how you have defined it?

Comment: I had an alias gco='git checkout', unfortunately git checkout -b test throws the same error. There are tons of commits in the repo. › git --version
git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
fatal: Unknown commit origin/test